# I am trying to update my number with current value get from textinput in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a program in javaScript in which I want to update number with current
field.
Suppose the number in the field is 5 and then I enter 4 in textfield then the field is updated
with number 9

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log("Button clicked")
  var newTotal = 0
  var input = parseInt(document.getElementById('text').value)
  newTotal = input
  if (newTotal) {
    console.log(newTotal)
    newTotal += input
  }
  console.log(newTotal)
  document.getElementById('textField').innerHTML = newTotal
  document.getElementById('text').value = ''
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<h3><span id="textField">0</span></h3>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Add Numbers">
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you want to add your new input to your previously saved total value, you might want to extract that value from `#textField` and then add the value of the `#text` input to it. Now you're just taking the value from the `#text` input and adding it to itself.

Comment: `if (0) { ... }` will never enter the if block. 0 is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this brother. You have to assign 0 to the `newTotal` outside of the function. Because if you put it inside the function, every time the function is called, the `newTotal` will become 0 and then will add the new input to itself.

Than you.

```js
let newTotal = 0

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const input = parseInt(document.getElementById('text').value)
  if (input) {
     newTotal += input
  }
  
  document.getElementById('textField').innerHTML = newTotal
  document.getElementById('text').value = ''
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<h3><span id="textField">0</span></h3>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Add Numbers">
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I want

Comment: I would not use `const`, because the browser blames that you cannot change the value. Use let or var instead.

Comment: @Reporter I didn't use const `const` where the value is changeable like `newTotal `. But `input` is not changing throughout the calculation. That's why IMHO, we can use const for `input` as it's a best practice to use const. Thanks, brother.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('text')

        //onchange event to update the value
        .addEventListener('change', () => {

            //checking if the input is valid integer and alerting
            var val = document.getElementById("text").value;
            if ( +val !== +val) { 
                document.getElementById('text').value = '';
                alert("Enter valid Number");
                throw new Error("Enter valid Number");
            }
            //if the input in valid integer then adding
            document.getElementById("textField").innerHTML = 
                parseInt(document.getElementById("textField").innerHTML) + parseInt(val);
            
            document.getElementById('text').value = '';
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Check</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <h3><span id="textField">0</span></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Here throwing error and alerting are optional,